# Ошибка при добавлении cookie в Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Прошу помощи в добавлении куки. Пишу интернет магазин и необходимо реализовать корзину с помощью файлов куки. Сейчас, при тестировании, я пытаюсь их добавить напрямую. Но вылетает эта ошибка:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Username is changed!], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Username is changed!], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Контроллеры:

```
//добавляет значение куки

  @GetMapping("/change-name")
    public String setCookie(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String name) {
        // create a cookie
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", "hoody");

        //add cookie to response
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return "Username is changed!";
    }

//выводит значение

    @GetMapping("/name")
    public String readCookie(@CookieValue(value = "name") String name) {
        return "Hey! My username is " + name;
    }
```

позже будет обращение к переменной через форму.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем причина ошибки и какие варианты ее исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы возвращаете значение типа String.
Spring Boot интерпретирует возвращаемое значение как имя view и, т.к. шаблона/view с именем `Username is changed!` не существует, то спринг кидает ошибку.
Чтобы исправить - возвращайте правильное значение с [правильным типом](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types).